# Wallpaper change crontab jobs not working after upgrade from 8.04 to 10.04

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, cron, cron-jobs, crontab

I have a crontab job set. It is a script to change the Desktop background wallpaper every 3 minutes. It was perfectly working before upgrading from Hardy to Lucid. When upgraded to Lucid, the wallpaper changes only when I login. It shows new wallpaper everytime I logout and login again or after restarting. It shows the same wallpapers which were set as the cron job script path.

Is crontab feature changed in Lucid? What is happening? Please help.

Comment: Do the commands contained in the crontab work if you enter them in a terminal? The change may be with nautilus (that handles the desktop background) rather than with cron.

Comment: Yes the command perfectly works in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Does your script include a call to gconftool-2 to set the wallpaper?  This relies on certain gnome / dbus environment variables being set, and they won't be set in the environment in which cron runs.

For a workaround see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1334355):

For a bug report on this, see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cron/+bug/327190):

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting post about that 'problem' give it a try [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9277193) hope its help cheers!

Comment: The link you gave was a good one. I followed the suggested answer but it dint work for me.

Comment: Damn well you can try deleting using other script instead?  Try this one maybe? http://www.webupd8.org/2009/11/3-lines-script-to-automatically-change.html

Comment: I have the same script which is given in three lines as a single line script. I tried scheduler (GUI) for cron too before asking this question here. Its not working either. My cron is running fine. I checked using `status cron` command. But the job is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (does not solve your problem..... just avoids having it ;) ):

I had a quite bunch of images (over 300) I wanted to rotate on my screen.... so I made [this script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/554740/). It goes through all of them (jpg's only in may case, but can be modified if there are other types) and creates an xml file (called `bg.xml`). *You can chose this latest file, `bg.xml`, as a rotating wallpaper*.

You can set `INTERVAL` to 180 (seconds) and `TRANSITION` according to your preferences (and any other thing you like, of course).

Hope it helps :)